# How do I modify a character vector so I can use it to to index another object? (raster or dataframe)

Tags: r

Say I have a raster object, r, (or a dataframe as they can be indexed similarly), and a character list, v:

```
v <- c("X15_X14","X15_X10","X13_X10")
```

The names/bands of my object "r" are "X1", "X2", ..., "X14", "X15"

What combination of strsplit, gsub, and paste (or any other function) can I use to create a simple math operation where "X15_X14" from my list becomes r$X15/r$X14 or r[[15]]/r[[14]]?

I want to use the list "v" I automatically generate to select bands/columns to perform division on.  I have a number of models where the training data is already in this ratio format (i.e. X15/X14) and is named like my list.  The data I'm applying the model to is named "X14", "X15" and needs to have the ratios applied before I can apply the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `strsplit` to split at `_` into a `list` of vectors, then loop over the `list` with `lapply`, subset the 'r' with `[[` and divide

```
lst1 <- lapply(strsplit(v, "_"), function(x) r[[x[1]]]/r[[x[2]]])
```

Comment: I was trying to use lapply to generate the list of what should be indexed, not directly performing the calculation there.  So this solution works well for my needs and is simple.  Thanks!